# jsconfig.json paths not working when importing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

Error: Cannot find package '@tables/db_question.js' imported from... `src\routes\question_route.js
This is my file directory:

```
root
|── src
|    └── database
|    |       └── tables
|    |              └── db_question.js
|    |── routes
|          └── question_route.js
|── node_modules
```

db_question.js

```
export function post() {
    
}
```

question_route.js

```
import express from "express";
const questionRouter = express.Router();
// import * as questionDatabase from "../database/tables/db_question.js";
import * as questionDatabase from "@tables/db_question.js"; // this doesn't work

// POST /question
questionRouter.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("works")
})

export default questionRouter;
```

So I'm importing from `src/database/tables/db_question.js` into `src/routes/question_route.js`
There doesn't seem to be much jsconfig.json answers on stackoverflow or on the web...

Comment: Let's configure `paths` in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Hi sorry do you mind elaborating?

Comment: You have to update your tsconfig file to configure  the paths setting.

Comment: Even if I am not using typescript? Do you have any link or answer so that I know better how to configure this?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases

Answer (score 0):

create a jsconfig.json in your root folder and add set up the base URL and paths

```
{
```

"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
"@tables/*": ["Tables/*"],

```
}
```

}
}

Then you would be able to use `import * as questionDatabase from "@tables/db_question.js"`